# regex to match a specific character but is optional

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Consider the following strings

```
home
administrator
admin
admin/
admin/users/index
```

and `preg_match("/^admin\/?(P<controller>[a-z-]+)?\/?(?P<action>[a-z-]+)?$/i", $input_line, $output_array);`

it is working to match the last 3 strings as expected, but also matches 'administrator' returning 'istrator' as the "controller"

How do I make the '/' optional, but any other character not count.  I have tried things like `[^a-z]\/?` but am at a loss.  Is it possible?

the logic is;
1. match `admin`
2. next character(s) are all optional
2.1 if next character exists, it must be `/`

live example https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/oaQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use optional non-capturing groups as containers around the named capturing groups where the patterns can be obligatory:

```
'~^admin(?:\/(?P<controller>[a-z-]+))?(?:\/(?P<action>[a-z-]+))?\/?$~i'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wVJ3Av/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `admin` - the `admin` substring
- `(?:\/(?P<controller>[a-z-]+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 repetitions of

  - `\/` - a `/` char
  - `(?P<controller>[a-z-]+)` - Group `controller`: 1+ ASCII letters or `-` (also, consider using `[^\/]+` instead to match any 1+ chars other than `/`)
- `(?:\/(?P<action>[a-z-]+))?` - Group `action`: 1+ ASCII letters or `-` (also, consider using `[^\/]+` instead to match any 1+ chars other than `/`)
- `\/?` - an optional `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: thanks for the details, this was not obvious to me. (it is part of an MVC router if that was not obvious)